# asp.net After a Server.Transfer how do you get the path of the current page?

Tags: asp.net

To get the url of the current page, I usually do something like this:

```
string path = Request.Path;
```

If I do this after a Server.Transfer then I get the path of the page where the transfer was done. How can I get it for the current page?

For example:

On Page1.aspx  I do Server.Transfer ("Page2.aspx")
On Page2.aspx  Request.Path returns /Page1.aspx and not /Page2.aspx

I would like to get /Page2.aspx. How can I get it?

Comment: Do you mean `Server.Transfer`?

Comment: Exact. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.currentexecutionfilepath.aspx) property.

Comment: You can use Request.QueryString to get the query string of the current page as well, so the full URL will be 
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?" + Request.QueryString.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

AppRelativeVirtualPath (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.apprelativevirtualpath.aspx) seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Server.Transfer, despite the URL on browser doesn't change, the Request references URL does. So, you may use the UrlReferrer property's Request. 
UrlReferrer gets information about the URL of the client's previous request that linked to the current URL.

For instance

```
string myContextBrowserPath = Context.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath
```